# Having issues with declaring activity in Manifest

Tags: android

I have two projects. test1 is a library. Whenever I try to open the activity in test1, I get an error saying Unable to find explicit activity class, have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml. Here are the files I'm working with.

test2.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.test2"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activty
        android:name="com.example.test1.OtherActivity"/>
</application>

</manifest>
```

test2's MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.test2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, 1, Menu.NONE, "Go to Library Project");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(this, com.example.test1.OtherActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

    return true;        
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a spelling mistake in

```
<activty
    android:name="com.example.test1.OtherActivity"/>
```

It should be

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.test1.OtherActivity"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this link, it will describe you how to add a library project. What i think you didn't add the activity to its manifest.

[Managing Projects from Eclipse with ADT](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject)

Comment: I do add the activity to the manifest.

    <activty
        android:name="com.example.test1.OtherActivity"/>

Comment: @user1132897 check your question, i've edited it.

Comment: Those need to be reviewed so I won't be able to see it for a bit. And now other people won't be able to see what problem I was originally faced with. Any chance you can just post what you did in your own answer?

Comment: I've edited this line **final Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OtherActivity.class);**

Comment: Post the logcat please, it is unclear what is actually happening there.